# PHP PDO connection showing 2 @ symbols on GoDaddy connection string

Tags: php, pdo, hosted

My code has been working on GoDaddy for months, I haven't touched it, but now something happened and I'm seeing

"Could not connect to the database :SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'readonly@localhost'@'www.biosistemasing.com' (using password: YES)"

1. I have no idea what [www.biosistemasing.com](http://www.biosistemasing.com) is
2. I have deleted my entire code base and re-uploaded from backup
3. I have tried adding different readonly@localhost, @%, etc
4. I have verified the username/password still work

Why is PDO attaching a different @ at the end of my connection and how do I fix that?

```
***
    $host     = 'host_ip_address';
    $db_name  = 'dbname';
    $username = 'readonly';
    $password = 'password';
    $dbh      = null;
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $username, $password);
        echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.";
    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe- 
       >getMessage());
    }
***
```